# Mean excluding outliers using dplyr

Tags: r, statistics

I was wondering if there is a way to compute the mean excluding outliers using the dplyr package in R? I was trying to do something like this, but did not work:

```
library(dplyr)
w = rep("months", 4)
value = c(1, 10, 12, 9)
df = data.frame(w, value)
output = df %>% group_by(w) %>% summarise(m = mean(value, na.rm = T, outlier = T))
```

So in above example, output should be 10.333 (mean of 10, 12, & 9) instead of 8 (mean of 1, 10, 12, 9)

Thanks!

Comment: Why exactly are we to think that 1 is an outlier?

Comment: @BondedDust Ah..I should have defined it. For my purpose, outlier is the value which has maximum difference from the mean.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

One way would be something like this using the `outlier` package.

```
library(outliers) #containing function outlier
library(dplyr)

df %>%
    group_by(w) %>%
    filter(!value %in% c(outlier(value))) %>%
    summarise(m = mean(value, na.rm = TRUE))

#       w        m
#1 months 10.33333
```

Comment: @PrakharMehrotra Thank you for your comment. I am glad to hear this is helpful. One note. As BondedDust mentioned, you may need to consider how you define outliers.

Comment: Your answer has helped me to understand how to manipulate the code I was struggling with to filter away outliers. Here you could find my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649237/how-to-delete-rows-of-outliers-rom-a-nested-dataset-via-an-iterative-method-or-p/69652445#69652445

Comment: @mały_statystyczny I am glad that this old post still helps you. :)

Comment: If you think to lend your long expertise for another issue, if I am allowed ì, I would invite to have a look at the my new post I am in trouble with. Please just feel no pressure to provide an answer. Thanks https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69675243/how-to-report-repeated-measures-anova-output-in-tables-on-a-word-text-file