# Removing/Filtering rows based on condition in R

Tags: r, conditional-statements, filtering

I would like to remove participants who scored 2 in column EXP_MAN and 1 in Ethnicity_Rescuer.

I used the following code and it worked.

```r
mydata <- mydata %>% 
  mutate(to_exclude = 
           case_when(EXP_MAN == 2 & 
                       (Ethnicity_Rescuer ==1) ~ 1)) %>%
  mutate(to_exclude = replace(to_exclude, is.na(to_exclude), 0))

mydata <- mydata %>% filter(to_exclude == 0)
```

However, this code seems very complicated and I am sure there should be a simpler solution.

I tried to filter out participants with the below code but it did not work. Just wondering what is the simplest code for removing participants in this case.

```r
mydata <- mydata %>% filter(EXP_MAN != 2 & Ethnicity_Rescuer !=1)
```

Comment: `mydata <- mydata %>% filter(EXP_MAN != 2 & Ethnicity_Rescuer !=1)` is looking correct. What do you mean it is not working? Is R returning some error?

Comment: I'm struggling with a similar problem. Here the link website page https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69649237/how-to-delete-rows-of-outliers-rom-a-nested-dataset-via-an-iterative-method-or-p/69652445#69652445. Could anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

You can use subset function to select a dataset and one/several conditions

```
subset(mydata,EXP_MAN != 2 & Ethnicity_Rescuer !=1)
```

Comment: So in the case of the code that I used, I removed only one participant who scored 2 in EXP_MAN and 1 in Ethnicity_Rescuer, which is what I wanted. 
In the case of other code, ```mydata <- mydata %>% filter(EXP_MAN != 2 & Ethnicity_Rescuer !=1)``` (as well as suggested ```subset(mydata,EXP_MAN != 2 & Ethnicity_Rescuer !=1```, it removes all participants who scored 1 or 2 on either of these two variables (so over 170 of them).

Comment: Wasn't this what you wanted, removing all patients with both conditions? "I would like to remove participants who scored 2 in column EXP_MAN and 1 in Ethnicity_Rescuer"

Comment: It removed those who scored 1 OR 2 not 2 and 2 ...